# How does the Cross-Correlation Function of these two series suggest "bove average value of SOI is likely to lead to a below average value of..."?

Tags: cross-correlation

[image]

```
library(astsa)
soi= scan("soi.dat")
rec = scan("recruit.dat")
soi=ts (soi)
rec = ts(rec)
ccfvalues =ccf (soi, rec)
ccfvalues
```

Reproduce these results with https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat510/lesson/8/8.2.

How is it determined from this cross-correlation plot that:

> Note! The correlations in this region are negative, indicating that an
> above average value of SOI is likely to lead to a below average value
> of “recruit” about 6 months later. And, a below average of SOI is
> associated with a likely above average recruit value about 6 months
> later.??

Comment: That's a standard interpretation of any negative correlation.

Comment: Why is six the cut-off line? There's nothing special about lag six in the CCF.

Comment: There's no cutoff: plenty of the cross-correlations are negative.  However, they are *most* negative (among all positive lags) at six months.